# Nginx Auto Domain Redirection

Tags: nginx, domain, redirect, wildcard

I'm trying to setup Nginx config to auto redirect any domain/subdomain pointed(CNAME) to my static subdomain(site.domain.com) to a respective directory inside /var/www. The directory will be named after the pointed domain/subdomain. I don't want to use VirtualHost or alter/restart Nginx everytime someone add new domain.

I stumble upon [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/381678/is-it-possible-to-configure-nginx-to-allow-for-new-domains-to-be-added-without-m) but I still don't quite understand. What should I set as root directory?

current config :

```
server {
    server_name site.domain.com;
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic nginx domain root path based on hostname?](http://serverfault.com/questions/457196/dynamic-nginx-domain-root-path-based-on-hostname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rewrite  ^(.*)$  /$host/$1;
```

Add the above mentioned rewrite rule. This works as following.
**xyz.foo.com/index.html** will map to **/var/www/xyz.foo.com/index.html**

The caveat is if the domain/subdomain directory doesn't exist nginx will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks, it works! However xyz.foo.com doesn't default to xyz.foo.com/index.html, any solution for this?

Comment: You can add the index directive http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpIndexModule#index

Comment: Already did that as per my original post. It works well before I add the rewrite rule. Now it return 404 error page.